# Crawl site getting URL and status code

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

I wrote a crawler that for every page visited collects the status code.
Below my solution. Is this code optimizable?

```
import urllib

def getfromurl(url):
    start = urllib.urlopen(url)
    raw = ''
    for lines in start.readlines():
        raw += lines                   
    start.close()
    return raw

def dumbwork(start_link, start_url, text, pattern, counter):
    if counter < 2:
        counter = counter +1
        while start_link != -1:
            try:
                start_url = text.find('/', start_link) 
                end_url = text.find('"', start_url + 1)
                url = 'http:/' + text[start_url + 1 : end_url]
                page_status = str(urllib.urlopen(url).getcode())
                row = url + ', ' + page_status
                t.write(row + '\n')
                temp = str(getfromurl(url))
                print row
                dumbwork(temp.find(pattern), 0, temp, pattern, counter)
                start_link = text.find(pattern, end_url + 1) 
            except Exception, e:
                break
    else:
        pass

t = open('inout.txt', 'w')
text = str(getfromurl('http://www.site.it'))
pattern = '<a href="http:/'
start_link = text.find(pattern)
dumbwork(start_link, 0, text, pattern, 0)
t.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview ! Won't `return (requests.head(url)).status_code` from [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module do this for you ? I'm usually using this module as it's straight-forward and you have like _a lot_ less headaches if you use it over `urllib`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You're taking for granted that a link will be `'<a href="http:/'`, which is definitely not always the case. What about `https://` for example, or if you have something like `'<a class="visited" href="http:/'` ? That's why you should use a library to parse the DOM objects instead of relying on raw text parsing.
- Naming:

  - usually a `row` is related to a database, while a `line` is related to a text file.
  - `temp` means nothing, it's the new content, so you should use something like `new_html_content`.
  - It takes a bit to understand that `counter` is actually the max depth that you want to follow, so why not call it `depth`
  - Function names should explain what they do, `dumbwork` name doesn't, something like `recurse_page` may be better.
  - `start_link` is good for the first link (almost, see below) but the parameter to the function is actually the current link being parsed, so why not call it `current_link`?
  - You used snake case for `start_link`, you should keep using it, so `get_from_url` may be better.
  - `start_link`, `start_url` and `end_url` are not links or urls, they're actually the index of the string, so they should be `start_link_index`, `start_url_index` and `end_url_index`
  - `text` is the HTML content, so just rename it to `html_content`
- The lines doing something with `row` should be next to each other, or better yet, in a separate function.
- That `2` should be in a constant so that the first line of the function can be something like `if depth < MAX_DEPTH:`
- You're trapping exceptions but you're not doing anything with them, you should at least log somewhere what happened.
- The text.find to get the url are probably better off in a separate function, to improve readability, something like
- `getfromurl` already returns a string, no need for the `str()`
- You're using always the same name for the file which, when opened with `w` will overwrite the contents. You should at least check if the file already exists.
- You're opening a file and leaving it open for the whole duration of the process. This is not bad in itself, but I'd probably put a function called `append_to_file` where I open the file with `a` instead of `w`, write the line and immediately close it. Inside of that function you will also convert the status code to a string.

In the end, your worker loop may look something like this:

```
def recurse_page(current_link_index, start_index, html_content, pattern, depth):
    if depth < MAX_DEPTH:
        depth += 1
        while current_link_index > -1:
            try:
                url = get_url(html_content, start_index)
                append_to_file(url, urllib.urlopen(url).getcode())
                new_html_content = get_from_url(url)
                recurse_page(new_html_content.find(pattern), 0, new_html_content, pattern, depth)
                current_link_index = html_content.find(pattern, end_url_index + 1) 
            except Exception, e:
                # TODO: Proper error handling
                break
```

It's not complete code, but it should give you an idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this, it makes it a lot easier.

An example of what you want to do with these two modules:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get("url")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")

for item in soup.find_all(href=True):
    link = item.get("href")
    # use link
```

BeautifulSoup has a lot of other useful searching functionality as well, for example if you only wanted links in 'a' blocks, you could use

```
for item in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    link = item.get("href")
    # use link
```

To install these modules use `pip install requests` and `pip install beautifulsoup4` in your terminal.